# Spark Console Progress Bar Missing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

How to get 'Stage' Console Progress Bar in Jupyter Notebook?

Progress bar was displayed earlier, but somehow it is not displayed now. I couldn't relate it to an Nbextension either.

Let me know if there is any configuration available to enable it back.

```
[Stage X:==========>            (A + B) / C]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `spark.ui.showConsoleProgress` to `True` [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: The flag was enabled and progress bar was seen once. It got disabled on its own. Might be something overrides?

Comment: yes possibly, it depends on your current system, who and which can control and change those settings (`spark-defaults.conf`, HDP configurations, etc). But technically, you can re-override it at the application level.